# How do you call a stored function in batch with JOOQ?

Tags: postgresql, jooq, postgresql-9.5

I want to call a stored function multiple times in batch. I'm using JOOQ 3.7.3 and PostgreSQL 9.5. I have tried using `select [function call]` statement in batch but it throws the following exception `PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected`.

```
 // exemplary 'select [function call]'
 context.batch(context.select(Routines.foo(someParam))).execute();
```

I have found no other way to call stored functions with JOOQ in batch.
I know it is possible with raw JDBC with [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) so I'm assuming it should also be possible with JOOQ.

Is it possible with JOOQ to call stored functions in batch? If yes, how to do it?

Stored function signature:

```
create function foo(param1 int, param2 int) returns boolean as $$ ... $$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Can you post the signature of your function (in pgplsql)?

Comment: @LukasEder done, I've also tried returning `boolean` value, it seems that the problem is that jdbc cannot handle stored function calls if it is not handled by the special `call` syntax with CallableStatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select [function call]` syntax is supported by the latest 9.4.1208 postgres jdbc driver. I was using 9.4.1205 version.

If you use the latest (9.4.1208) jdbc driver you can use the following syntax if the stored function returns some value:

```
Query query1 = context.select(Routines.foo(someParam));
Query query2 = context.select(Routines.foo(someParam));
context.batch(query1, query2).execute();
```

If the stored function returns `void` you can use:

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo(); foo1.setParam(someParam);
Foo foo2 = new Foo(); foo2.setParam(someParam);
context.batch(context.select(foo1.asField()), context.select(foo2.asField())).execute();
```

Comment: To use `Routines.foo(someParam)` the stored function needs to return some value other than `void`. Jooq doesn't generate helper methods in `Routines` class if the stored function returns `void`.